# Just_audio with loudness enhancer and just_audio_background

Tags: just-audio

I have been trying to use just_audio (0.9.18) with the loudness enhancer and just_audio_background (0.0.1-beta.3) getting an error:   UnimplementedError: androidLoudnessEnhancerSetTargetGain() has not been implemented.
I am using the provided Github effects example which runs as expected but throws the Unimplemented error if just_audio_background is added as per instructions. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all features are supported on all federated implementations, and you get this error to indicate that that feature isn't supported. You could submit a feature request (as opposed to a bug report) to the project.